# ^= operator in Python

Tags: python

I've been using Python a while and I bumped into this operator "^=" for the first time from this [link](https://codesays.com/2015/solution-to-odd-occurrences-in-array-by-codility/).

```
def solution(A):
    result = 0
    for number in A:
        result ^= number
    return result
```

Of course, I did some googling, but I can't seem to find this operator. What does it do?

Comment: In my experience, the Python docs are absurdly hard to Google. Including "Python language reference" in your search can often lead to better results.

Comment: it is xor......

Comment: It is not exactly the same as the question I linked, though. `^` is the XOR operator. `^=` is the XOR-assignment operator, so `a ^= b` means "assign `a XOR b` to `a`".

Comment: For some reason, the python docs don't list `^=` in the assignment operators reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `^` operator yields the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) of its arguments, which must be integers.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

As with all the other `_=` operators, `^=` assigns the result back to the variable: `a =^ b` is eqivalent to `a = a ^ b`.

As a function it is `__ixor__` (or [`operator.ixor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)), and may have different behaviour for non-integer types.

Comment: What do you mean with "on an object"? Everything in Python is an object, and it may or may not have `__ixor__` implemented.

Comment: Ah, okay. I wasn't sure if you were trying to say that numbers are primitive data types like in Java (your top tag).

Answer (score 3):

The special method that relates to `^=` and is called behind the curtains is `__ixor__`. The special method that relates to `^` is `__xor__`. They don't have to behave the same.

[**`__ixor__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ixor__) is the [**Augmented Assignment**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) variant of [**`__xor__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__xor__), performing inplace operations when possible, and falling back to `__xor__` when `__ixor__` is not implemented.

In principle, the return value of the method is completely up to the implementation of `__ixor__`, but there are some common use cases.

For two sets, `a ^= b` computes the **symmetric difference** of the sets `a` and `b` (all elements present in exactly one of the two sets) and *mutates* `a`.

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = {1, 4, 5}
>>> reference = a
>>> 
>>> a ^= b
>>> a
{2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> reference
{2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Note that `a` has been mutated *in place*, thus `a` and `reference` both point to the same `set` object `{2, 3, 4, 5}` in memory. Thus `^=` behaves differently from `^` in this case, which *builds a new set* as shown below.

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = {1, 4, 5}
>>> reference = a
>>> a = a^b
>>> a
{2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> reference
{1, 2, 3}
```

Note that `a = a^b` has built a new set to which the name `a` has been *reassigned* and `reference` still refers to the original set `{1, 2, 3}`.

For builtin *immutable* types (like integers), `a ^= b` is indeed equivalent to `a = a^b`. Since integers have no `__ixor__` method, Python falls back to using `__xor__`.
In the case of integers `a ^= b` performs a **bitwise-non-equal** operation and the name `a` is reassigned to the result of that computation.

Demo:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 6
>>> a^b
3
```

Explanation:

```
    101 (5 decimal)
XOR 110 (6 decimal)
-------------------
    011 (3 decimal)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is XOR. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations
For example:

```
9 ^ 1
```

Output:

```
8
```

Because in binary `9` is `101`, then `1` is `001`.
XOR operation mean:

```
101
001
output:
100 #or 8 in natural number
```

Answer (score 1):

`a ^= b` equialent to `a = a^b`

`^` - is [XOR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) operator